# How to select certain values from JSON to build Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I use the `requests` module to hit an endpoint and get back a JSON response:

```
response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=(user_name, api_key)).json()
```

The response looks like this:

```
{'SalesInfoStatus': {'next_offset': 15,
  'sales': [{'saSalesID': '761S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '761',
    'origin': 'New York',
    'destination': 'London',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/19/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/19/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '761S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'},
   {'saSalesID': '762S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '762',
    'origin': 'New York',
    'destination': 'London',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/17/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/17/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '762S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'},

   {'saSalesID': '765S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '765',
    'origin': 'Paris',
    'destination': 'Tokyo',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/15/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/15/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '765S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'},

   {'saSalesID': '767S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',
    'identifier': '767',
    'origin': 'Los Angeles',
    'destination': 'Sydney',
    'filed_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/13/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
     'actual_time': {'epoch': 1666033349,
     'time': '15:02',
     'date': '10/13/2022',
     'localtime': 1666018949},
    'inbound_saSalesID': '767S-1666029229-adhoc-0:0'}

]}}
```

When I call `type(response)`, I get `dict`.

I would like to build a Pandas dataframe that contains the `date`, `origin`, `destination`, and `identifier` fields from this JSON.

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
date         origin          destination     identifier
10/19/22     New York        London          761
10/17/22     New York        London          762
10/15/22     Paris           Tokyo           765
10/13/22     Los Angeles     Sydney          767
```

I'm using the following:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(response)
```

But, this returns a dataframe with a column containing what appears to be nested JSON:

```
                   SalesInfoStatus
    sales          [{'saSalesID': '761S-1666031549-adhoc-0:0',... 
    next_offset    15
```

How would I split the `date`, `origin`, `destination` and `identifier` fields out into their own columns in this dataframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.json_normalize` on the list value of `sales` key

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(response['SalesInfoStatus']['sales'])[['filed_time.date', 'origin', 'destination', 'identifier']]
```

```
print(df)

  filed_time.date       origin destination identifier
0      10/19/2022     New York      London        761
1      10/17/2022     New York      London        762
2      10/15/2022        Paris       Tokyo        765
3      10/13/2022  Los Angeles      Sydney        767
```